# facebook auto-expanding like box

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

can anyone provide me any ideas about how to import a facebook like box, in my site. I would it to seem like the one in the folowing site "http://www.babyspace.gr/". Does any  of the existing javascript frameworks afford such a functionality?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is simple Facebook social plugin called Like Box and you can get it here: http://developers.facebook.com/plugins?footer=1

You can install it on any webpage quite easily - If you follow the instructions on the page linked above.

About the slider - It can be achieved quite easily with jQuery. Put the Like Box on some div and use jQuery animate to show it by click.